# Default properties for object while destructuring parameters

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a component that takes a `placeholder` (string) and a source (more complex object). The placeholder and many properties of `source` have to be provided when the function is called, but I want to provide a default value for one of the source properties if it's not provided when it's called:

```
const Component = ({ placeholder, source }) => {
  source.priority = source.priority ? source.priority : 'normal';
```

Is there a way to do this with destructuring assignment? The closest I can come is the following, but this gives me "parameter source cannot be referenced in its initializer."

```
const Component = ({ placeholder, source = { priority: 'normal', ...source } })
```

Comment: I believe `const Component = ({ placeholder, source = { priority: 'normal'} })` should do the trick. Or your `source` should have some more default properties?

Comment: That doesn't work because if `source` is not provided it will just be set to `{ priority }`, but it needs more properties than that. I want to use the properties provided by the user and provide a default for `priority` if one isn't given.